# Update SQS Trigger Concurrency from Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sqs, hashicorp

I need some help with terraform code to set the Maximum concurrency of an SQS to 50.
The problem is I am using hashicorp/aws/4.28.0 version where scaling_config is not available. The latest version of aws provides this feature. So how to achieve the same functionality in the lower version of hashicorp/aws/?
Doc reference: [5.0.0](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_event_source_mapping) , [4.28.0](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/4.28.0/docs/resources/lambda_event_source_mapping#scaling_config)

[image]

Comment: Well you can't if you don't want to upgrade TF. The only way is to use `local-exec` with AWS CLI to do it.

Comment: decided to do it manually from the console. As Terraform does not detect the key "maximum concurrency" the pipeline is not updating the value so its ok for me to just update from the console. Thanks for the "local-exec" suggestion as well @Marcin

Answer (score 1):

The maximum concurrency should be set in the lambda event source mapping-

```
resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "event_source_mapping1" {
    event_source_arn = "yourFifoQueue.fifo"
    enabled          = true
    function_name    = yourLambdaArn
    batch_size       = 1
    scaling_config {
        maximum_concurrency = 5
    }
}
```